# Unset git configuration

Tags: git

I am using FileMerge on Mac for viewing diffs and have set it up with:

```
git config --global diff.external ~/bin/git-diff-cmd.sh
```

Now I no longer want to use FileMerge, how do I go back to the default I had before this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `--unset` [From the man page:](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

```
--unset
    Remove the line matching the key from config file.
```