# This command broke my GitHub, how do I fix it

Tags: github, ssh, terminal

I ran this command:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

and now am running into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7iX8.png) authentication error with GitHub desktop.

I don't need to use SSH anymore and want to "undo" the command. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unset git configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974147/unset-git-configuration)

Comment: Global user configuration is saved in `~/.gitconfig` Edit this file to remove the config lines.

Comment: Going into ~/.gitconfig and editing the file fixed it. Thank you so much